Unable to install and use torch through CUDA and VSCode
I have set up Anaconda environment and downloaded CUDA and CuDNN in it. I also have tensorflow installed via conda (not tensorflow-gpu) along with keras and scikit-learn. Once that is done, I am trying to launch VSCode to run my code in it. I ran these two lines
import torch
torch.cuda.is_available()

which returned True. However, when I try to run the import commands, I keep getting an error.
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Model
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import keras
import sklearn

which gave this error.
> A module that was compiled using NumPy 1.x cannot be run in NumPy
> 2.0.2 as it may crash. To support both 1.x and 2.x versions of NumPy, modules must be compiled with NumPy 2.0. Some module may need to
> rebuild instead e.g. with 'pybind11>=2.12'.
> 
> If you are a user of the module, the easiest solution will be to
> downgrade to 'numpy<2' or try to upgrade the affected module. We
> expect that some modules will need time to support NumPy 2.
> 
> Traceback (most recent call last):  File
> "c:\Users\name\anaconda3\envs\tensor_env_jupyter\lib\runpy.py", line
> 197, in _run_module_as_main
>     return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,   File "c:\Users\name\anaconda3\envs\tensor_env_jupyter\lib\runpy.py", line
> 87, in _run_code
>     exec(code, run_globals)   File "c:\Users\name\anaconda3\envs\tensor_env_jupyter\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py",
> line 18, in <module>
>     app.launch_new_instance()   File "c:\Users\name\anaconda3\envs\tensor_env_jupyter\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py",
> line 1075, in launch_instance
>     app.start()   File "c:\Users\name\anaconda3\envs\tensor_env_jupyter\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py",
> line 739, in start
>     self.io_loop.start()   File "c:\Users\name\anaconda3\envs\tensor_env_jupyter\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py",
> line 205, in start
>     self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()   File "c:\Users\name\anaconda3\envs\tensor_env_jupyter\lib\asyncio\base_events.py",
> line 601, in run_forever
>     self._run_once()   File "c:\Users\name\anaconda3\envs\tensor_env_jupyter\lib\asyncio\base_events.py",
> line 1905, in _run_once ...   File
> "c:\Users\name\anaconda3\envs\tensor_env_jupyter\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\__init__.py",
> line 295, in <module>
>     from ._csr import *   File "c:\Users\name\anaconda3\envs\tensor_env_jupyter\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\_csr.py",
> line 11, in <module>
>   

If I try to downgrade the library to 1.x, then I cannot import scikit-learn as it immediately upgrades numpy to 2.0.1.
Is there any fix for this?
(Note: I have a Geforce RTX 4070 card and these are the libraries inside the environment)
> (tensor_env_jupyter) PS C:\Users\name> conda list cudnn
> # packages in environment at C:\Users\name\anaconda3\envs\tensor_env_jupyter:
> #
> # Name                    Version                   Build  Channel cudnn                     8.2.1                cuda11.3_0
> (tensor_env_jupyter) PS C:\Users\name> conda list cudatoolkit
> # packages in environment at C:\Users\name\anaconda3\envs\tensor_env_jupyter:
> #
> # Name                    Version                   Build  Channel cudatoolkit               11.3.1               h59b6b97_2


None of the listed packages (in newer versions) should require numpy 1.x. Did you test which package installs numpy 1.x when gradually adding them to the env? Otherwise I'd just start with a fresh venv/conda environment, and install these packages again. Do you maybe have any old versions of these packages that you use?
